# Proof of: $f'(x) =$ $\lim_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ $\implies$ $f(x+h)-f(x) = hf'(x) + r(h)$, where $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{r(h)}{h}=0$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

From Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis:

> If $f$ is a real function with domain (a, b) $\subset$ $R^1$ and if $x$ $\in$ (a, b), then $f'(x)$
> is usually defined to be the real number $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \tag{1}$$ provided, of course, that this limit exists. Thus, $$f(x+h)-f(x) = hf'(x) + r(h) \tag{2}$$ where the "remainder" $r(h)$ is small, in the sense that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{r(h)}{h}=0 \tag{3}.$$

How does $(1)$ $\implies$ $(2)$?

From $(3)$, taking "anti-limit" (I don't know if this correct or not), $$\frac{r(h)}{h}=h \tag{4}$$ (apply $\lim_{h \to 0}$ on both sides, we will get back $(3)$) $$\implies r(h)=h^2 \tag{5}$$

Substituting $(5)$ in (2), $$f(x+h) - f(x) = f'(x)h + h^2\tag{6}$$ $\implies$ $$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x) - h^2}{h}=f'(x)\tag{7}$$
which seems to be not equal to $(1)$.

---

Edit: $(7)$ seems to be equal to $(1)$. Applying $\lim_{h \to 0}$ on both sides of $(7)$, seems to give back $(1)$. (As right hand side, f'(x) will have no h in it, after application of limit, it seems to stay the same as before).

---

It seems like right hand side of $(4)$ can be $$mh^n$$, where m, h can atleast $\epsilon$ $R$. I don't know may be extendable to $R^n$.

Comment: Do you have a typo in (1)? Shouldn't it be $f(x+h) - f(x) $ not $f(x) - h$.

Comment: @Gregory Thank you. I edited it.

Comment: Where does the equation $r(h) /h = h$ come from?

Comment: What is an "anti-limit"?

Comment: @KennyWong Hi. I don't know if this correct or not. If we apply $\lim_{h \to 0}$ on both sides of $(4)$, we will get back $(3)$. (Like antiderivative, anti limit?).

Comment: @Bernkastel Hi. Above comment might answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "anti limit" is wrong, I do not know how you derived it.

The natural way is :

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} =f'(x) \tag{A}$$ can be rewritten
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)+\varepsilon(h)\tag{B}$$
where $$\lim_{h \to 0}\varepsilon(h)=0\tag{C}$$

Hence (2) :
$$f(x+h)-f(x) = hf'(x) + h\varepsilon(h) \tag{D}$$
and if you let $r(h)= h\varepsilon(h)$ you can see that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{r(h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \varepsilon(h) = 0  \tag{E}$$

Comment: You could add that the transformation to the $\varepsilon(h)$ form, comes from addition of limits. $\lim f(h)=a$ and $\lim \varepsilon(h)=0$ then $\lim (f(h)+\varepsilon(h))=a+0=a$ or equivalently $f(h)=a-\varepsilon(h)$ has limit $a$ but we ignore the sign as epsilon is arbitrary anyway.